# Transform a list of JSON string to a list of dict in Pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I’m struggling to transform a list of JSON string to a list of dict in Pyspark without using udf or using rdd

I have this kind of dataframe:

| Key | JSON_string |
| --- | --- |
| 123456 | ["""{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STA"}""","""{"City":"PARC","State":"PR"}"""] |
| 789123 | ["""{"Zipcode":7,"ZipCodeType":"AZA"}""","""{"City":"PRE","State":"XY"}"""] |

How can I transform `col(JSON_string)` by using built-in functions in Pyspark to  `[{"Zipcode":704,"ZipCodeType":"STA"},{"City":"PARC","State":"PR"}]` ?

I tried many functions such as create_map, collect_list, from_json, to_json, explode, json.loads, json.dump but no way to get the expected result.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Explode your `JSON_string` column, and read it as json, group by again.

```
df = df.withColumn('JSON_string', f.explode('JSON_string'))

schema = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda r: r.JSON_string)).schema

df_result = df.withColumn('JSON', f.from_json('JSON_string', schema)) \
  .drop('JSON_string') \
  .groupBy('Key') \
  .agg(f.collect_list('JSON').alias('JSON'))

df_result.show(truncate=False)
df_result.printSchema()

+------+------------------------------------------------+
|Key   |JSON                                            |
+------+------------------------------------------------+
|123456|[{null, null, STA, 704}, {PARC, PR, null, null}]|
|789123|[{null, null, AZA, 7}, {PRE, XY, null, null}]   |
+------+------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- Key: long (nullable = true)
 |-- JSON: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- City: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- State: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ZipCodeType: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Zipcode: long (nullable = true)
```